# How would I find the first 5 multiples of 4, 5, and 6 and add them to an ArrayList?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, multiplication, modulo

I have a homework assignment that needs me to write a method that, given a list, will remove all multiples of 3 and add the first 5 multiples of 4, 5, and 6. It will then add that list to a HashSet, removing the duplicate integers, and return the size of the HashSet.

I've figured out everything else in this problem save for the "add first 5 multiples of 4, 5, and 6". My current code is the one I'm stuck with, using a for loop to iterate from 1 to 30. However, given an empty list, this adds 28, which is the 7th multiple of 4. I've tried nesting loops so I can iterate to 30 while at the same time iterating to 5, but none of my attempts have worked. Can anyone help me out?

Below is my current code.

```
public static int modify(List<Integer> list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i) == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot be null.");
        }
        if (list.get(i) % 3 == 0) {
            list.remove(i);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++) {
        if (i % 4 == 0) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        if (i % 5 == 0) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        if (i % 6 == 0) {
            list.add(i);
        }
    }

    Collections.sort(list);
    HashSet<Integer> unique = new HashSet<Integer>();
    unique.addAll(list);
    return unique.size();
}
```

Comment: The first five multiples of 4, first five multiples of 5, and first five multiples of 6 or the first five of all the multiples of 4, 5, and 6?

Comment: Do you mean that you have to add the first five multiple of 4 (4 8 12 16 20) and first five multiples of five... or the first five numbers multiples of 4 and 5 and 6

Comment: @ElanHamburger the former. Input is an empty arrayList, and expected output is 13, but I'm getting 14 because it's adding the seventh multiple of 4, which is 28.

Comment: @AlexRudenko given a list he removes all multiples of 3, then adds the multiples of 4 etc. The empty list is used as test

Comment: @AlexRudenko technically yes, but it removes the multiples of 3 before it adds the multiples of 4, 5, and 6.

Comment: Add numbers not already in the list? And if so wouldn't say 12 count toward the next multiples of both 4 and 6? Sounds like you might need three counters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of counting to 30 and checking for incidences of multiples of 4, 5, and 6, why don't you find the multiples directly?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    list.add(4 * i);
    list.add(5 * i);
    list.add(6 * i);
}
```

If there are any duplicates, they'll be removed when you add them to the HashSet.

*Side note: I'm not sure why you're bothering to sort the list before you add them to the HashSet. Sets inherently have no order so it doesn't matter if the list is sorted or not.*

Comment: I'll try this out. Also, the only reason I'm sorting the list is because the assignment requires it.

Comment: Seems silly given that you just throw the list away once you add the elements to the set, but I guess I can't argue with the project requirements.

Comment: If you have to sort them i think you will need a LinkedHashSet. Since a HashSet has no links, some operations on the HashSet modify its order

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're expecting the output of passing in an empty list to be:

```
unique = [4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15, 16, 18, 20, 24, 25, 30]
size = 13
```

With your current logic, there's nothing stopping it from adding multiples which are more than 5 (i.e. the 7th multiple of 4 for example), you're just continuing on until you've hit 30 in the loop. Instead, I might recommend having your for loop go 1-5 and then multiply by the factor you'd like a multiple of. i.e.:

```
        // add the first 5 multiples of 4,5,6 to the list
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            list.add(i*4);
            list.add(i*5);
            list.add(i*6);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the whole method making some changes:

1. The removal part of multiples of 3 in this way is more efficient. I
   used the very useful [removeIf()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arraylist-removeif-method-in-java/) method.
2. I wrote the solution to your problem, identical to the other
   answers.

### CODE

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
     for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
         list.add(i);
     }
     System.out.println(modify(list));
}

public static int modify(List<Integer> list) {
    list.removeIf(n -> (n % 3 == 0));
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        list.add(4 * i);
        list.add(5 * i);
        list.add(6 * i);
    }
    Collections.sort(list);
    HashSet<Integer> unique = new HashSet<>(list);
    System.out.println(unique.toString()); // You can delete this
    return unique.size();
}
```

### OUTPUT

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 28, 29, 30]

26
```